# Want to place multiple hidden buttons over a background image?

Tags: android

Not able to set hidden buttons over the background image, want to place hidden buttons exactly over the words (i.e total 5 hidden buttons over background image). Help!.

Comment: can you show the image and where you want buttons.

Comment: you have to post something, this could be big, as placing Views is not soo easy in Android, you have to take care of multiple screen res/sizes, ...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `RelativeLayout` to do this (if you want to create a custom view, eg in corners). `RelativeLayout` is a Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent.

See this link: [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211484/how-to-place-buttons-over-image-in-android?rq=1) and information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760284/how-to-place-transparent-buttons-over-an-image-relatively?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout with button alpha 0%.

Also consider doing it in another way. It may go wrong on different screen sizes and orienantions.